# python dbf - add row of dict to existing file

Tags: python, dbf

I have a dbf file with following structure...

```
FieldnameList(['ORDNUMB C(10) SYSTEM', 'SIDE C(1) BINARY SYSTEM', 'POSITION C(3)', 'COMPTYPE C(2)', 'COMPCODE C(6)', 'COMPCODEEX C(10) SYSTEM', 'CRIBTYPE C(2) BINARY SYSTEM', 'DIAM1 C(2)', 'DIAM2 C(2)', 'DIAM3 C(2) NULL SYSTEM', 'PRSPH C(2)', 'PRTOR C(2)'])
```

And Im trying to add another row to it. What i have tried many different things but i cant seem to append dict to it the way i want. The problem is it does not find ORDNUMB field so for example

```
table.append( {'ORDNUMB': '633','POSITION': '6', } )
```

doesn't work, but the

```
table.append( {'POSITION': '6', } )
```

does. In first case i get an error that field ORDNUMB cant be found.

Maybe the problem is with the field that is regarded as system ?

Comment: Which library are you using?  `pandas`, `dbf`, something else?

Comment: Im using dbf but open to suggestions

Comment: Why have you declared your fields `SYSTEM`?  Drop that part of each field definition and it should work fine.

Comment: Its not my file. Im just appending the data to it.

Comment: Can you ask the source of that file why the fields are `SYSTEM`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `dbf` library, then the problem is that the `ORDNUMB` field is marked as `SYSTEM` -- this means that it is a hidden field and users are not allowed to update it as `dbf` will take care of any manipulations.  For example, tables that support null values for fields have that information tracked in a `_null` `SYSTEM` field.